# Users linking to old web pages

Tags: html, redirect, google-search-console

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

Company has two types of products, therefore two seperate webpages to serve up each:

products-professional.html

products-consumer.html

Company changes structure and now does not want to list products as seperate, new page is:

products.html

According to Google Webmaster Tools, some sites have links to our old pages. I've added a redirect on them to point them towards the new page, but the errors still show in Google Webmaster Tools. I don't want errors.

Comment: How did you add redirects? How long has it been?

Comment: use 301 redirect from old URL's to new URL's in your website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web server settings and related issues; consider asking in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i'd start with redirecting using 301 old pages to new pages then asking webmasters of those sites to update links to reflect a change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. monitor GWT errors and add missing redirects
2. try to contact as many as possible users linking to the old url's and ask them to fix it

Since 2'nd point is hard to achieve in 100%, your redirects has to be bulletproof, and even then google can find some weird urls from a year ago and report errors.